# dplyr group mutate to select row of last occurring index of a category giving error

Tags: r, dplyr

I have a data frame like this:

```
> df <- data.frame(x = c(1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2), type = c('a', 'a', 'a', 'b', 'a', 'a', 'b', 'a', 'b', 'a', 'b'))
> df
   x type
1  1    a
2  1    a
3  1    a
4  1    b
5  1    a
6  1    a
7  1    b
8  2    a
9  2    b
10 2    a
11 2    b
```

I want to mutate a new column such that the value is the last occurring row of type 'a' within each group for each row. Trying the following is giving me a warning and producing the wrong result. Not sure why this is wrong.

```
> df %>% group_by(x) %>% mutate(lastA = max(which(type[1:row_number()] == 'a')))
Source: local data frame [11 x 3]
Groups: x

   x type lastA
1  1    a     1
2  1    a     1
3  1    a     1
4  1    b     1
5  1    a     1
6  1    a     1
7  1    b     1
8  2    a     1
9  2    b     1
10 2    a     1
11 2    b     1
Warning messages:
1: In mutate_impl(.data, dots) :
  numerical expression has 7 elements: only the first used
2: In mutate_impl(.data, dots) :
  numerical expression has 4 elements: only the first used
```

My desired output in this case is as follows:

```
> dfout
   x type lastA
1  1    a     1
2  1    a     2
3  1    a     3
4  1    b     3
5  1    a     5
6  1    a     6
7  1    b     6
8  2    a     1
9  2    b     1
10 2    a     3
11 2    b     3
```

Comment: There is likely a simpler way, but you could add the `lastA` as the row number per group, replace with `NA` for `type == "b"` with `replace` or an `ifelse` and then fill in with `na.locf` from package *zoo*: `df %>% group_by(x) %>% mutate(lastA = ifelse(type == "a", row_number(), NA)) %>% na.locf()`

Comment: What do you want for lastA when for x=3, the first type is b?

Comment: I modified the data set to make it a bit more clear. Each 'type' may have multiple sequences of a/b, I want the b rows to assume the last row number of the last seen a.

Comment: You can also use the `fill` function from `tidyr` (only in dev versions right now), like @aosmith used na.locf above: `df %>% group_by(x) %>% mutate(lastA = ifelse(type == "a", row_number(), NA)) %>% fill(lastA)`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We can do this using `min_rank/cumsum`.  We group by 'x', then get the `cumsum` of logical index (`type=='a'`) and wrap it with `min_rank` to `rank` the output.

```
library(dplyr)
df %>%
   group_by(x) %>%
   mutate(lastA= min_rank(cumsum(type=='a')))
#  Source: local data frame [11 x 3]
#Groups: x [2]

#       x   type lastA
#   (dbl) (fctr) (int)
#1      1      a     1
#2      1      a     2
#3      1      a     3
#4      1      b     3
#5      1      a     5
#6      1      a     6
#7      1      b     6
#8      2      a     1
#9      2      b     1
#10     2      a     3
#11     2      b     3
```

Comment: Masterful. Could you please comment on why the way I was using max/which is failing though? Want to understand what that is doing that I am missing.

Comment: @user3949008  Based on the expected output, I am not sure why you are using `max` with `which`.  `which` only returns the position of those elements that satisfy the condition.  Suppose `v1 <- c(1:5,3); which(v1==3)`.  If we check the lengths, it returns 2 elements (in this example) when compared to the length of the original vector.  You may need `ifelse` to get the same length as the original vector.